# Embedding Google MapView crashes android app

Tags: android, google-maps

model : zt180
firmware : android 2.1-update1-20101030
kernel : 2.6.32.9 usbandroid #1608
build number zt180-eng 2.1-update1 20101030
google maps : 4.5.1

Various crashes occur when embedding the google maps component into an android application. I'm connecting to a router via Wi-Fi for internet access. The stand-alone google maps app seems to work fine. To re-produce, start the maps app and begin scrolling around.

Will fail within a couple of minutes, occasionally on start-up (in setContentView). Most of the errors are when drawing tiles in google code. Sometimes just an Android SEGV.

NOTE : I've tested the same app on the Android developer phone 2 (os 1.6), and it works fine.

My android app is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:id="@+id/mapView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:apiKey="043yBg1m9IiFNKXIhN5LsdeNndw2k7yrw4Ja3xQ"/>
</RelativeLayout>


import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Maps extends MapActivity {  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   
  }  
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { return false; }  
 }
```

=========================

```
W/MapActivity( 2745): Recycling dispatcher com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@45ebcd30
V/MapActivity( 2745): Recycling map object.
I/ActivityManager( 2010): Displayed activity com.brta.android.lite/.Maps: 720 ms (total 720 ms)
I/MapActivity( 2745): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
E/MapActivity( 2745): Couldn't get connection factory client
D/AndroidRuntime( 2745): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2745): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b168)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2745): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 2745): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented
E/AndroidRuntime( 2745): at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.checkPaintTimeExceeded(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2745): at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2745): at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2745): at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2745): at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
<snip>
I/Process ( 2745): Sending signal. PID: 2745 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager( 2010): Process com.brta.android.lite (pid 2745) has died.
I/WindowManager( 2010): WIN DEATH: Window{46112878 com.brta.android.lite/com.brta.android.lite.Maps paused=false}
I/UsageStats( 2010): Unexpected resume of org.adw.launcher while already resumed in com.brta.android.lite`
```

======================================================================

```
I/MapActivity( 2863): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
E/MapActivity( 2863): Couldn't get connection factory client
D/dalvikvm( 2863): GC freed 8114 objects / 577376 bytes in 86ms
D/dalvikvm( 2863): GC freed 685 objects / 444384 bytes in 85ms
D/dalvikvm( 2863): GC freed 3458 objects / 259456 bytes in 79ms
I/ActivityManager( 2010): Displayed activity com.brta.android.lite/.Maps: 4407 ms (total 4407 ms)
D/AndroidRuntime( 2863): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2863): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b168)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:331)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
<snip>
E/AndroidRuntime( 2863): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process ( 2010): Sending signal. PID: 2863 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 2863): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 2863): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process ( 2863): Sending signal. PID: 2863 SIG: 9
I/WindowManager( 2010): WIN DEATH: Window{460ac708 com.brta.android.lite/com.brta.android.lite.Maps paused=false}
I/ActivityManager( 2010): Process com.brta.android.lite (pid 2863) has died.
I/UsageStats( 2010): Unexpected resume of org.adw.launcher while already resumed in com.brta.android.lite
W/InputManagerService( 2010): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2863 uid 10046
```

Basically, lots of bad things start happening...

Answer (score 1):

The ZT-180 does not have Google Maps, AFAIK.

Comment: It has the standalone Google app and the embedded MapView component does (usually) start and show a map, until it crashes of course.

Comment: @brtancs: My point is that I do not think it ships with that app. If you obtained that app from some other ROM, then it's an unlicensed copy and you would have to ask the ROM modders why it is not working (and how they plan on not getting sued).